# How to create normal distribution time serires over a day in Excel?

Tags: excel, function, normal-distribution

I have to create a time series over a day, where the tops of that bell curves are around 7 a.m and 17 p.m. like any retail store transactions.
The scale is in hours.

Is there any solution to do this with formulas?

Thank you,

Comment: series* I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `NORM.DIST` function to do this. For example, the following formula in `A1:A24`

```
=NORM.DIST(ROW(), 7, 2,FALSE)+NORM.DIST(ROW(),17,2,FALSE)
```

will produce this chart:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's perfect.